# How to create line break in WhatsApp message?

Tags: php, whatsapp, line-breaks

I am working on PHP side to write dynamic messages for WhatsApp. But when i send message then unable to add new line break.
i have tried following codes inside content but not working for my case: **%0D  %0a \n \r\n %0D%0A**

i.e first line **\n** second line **%0a** third line **\r\n** fourth line **;br;** fifth line

Comment: you can use a richtext editor to handle it.

Comment: i am generating content from the server side(database). So it's not feasible.

Comment: store it in html form i.e using cke editor and then retrieve it such that html executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried
PHP_EQL and its working.

***i.e
echo "First Line".PHP_EQL."Second Line";***

**Output is**

First Line 
Second Line

Answer (score 0):

since you are publishing the page , you need to rather insert HTML like break using nl2br() This function will insert a newline wherever it finds \n
Example

```
<?php
echo nl2br("This is first line and.\n this is the second line.");
?>
```

**OUTPUT**
This is first line and
this is the second line

**So the HTML OUT will be like**

```
This is first line and <br/>this is the second line
```

Answer (score 0):

"\n"- should work
E.g
`$message .= "Enter 'menu' to return to main menu \n"; $this->whatsAppService->sendTextMessage($phoneNumber, $message);`